# Datomic Transactor URI for Peers on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, datomic

When deploying a transactor to AWS, how does a peer know the ip details of the transactor?

Does the transactor register this with DynamoDB and the Peer resolves it there?

Comment: It looks like there is a pod-coord key in DDB that contains the details the peers need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.
The details of endpoint discovery are described here:
http://docs.datomic.com/deployment.html#getting-connected